# capitalization of word from column A in a text from column B in csv file

Tags: python, csv

I Have a csv file with two columns A for brand's names Column B with descriptions

I want to capitalize the brands names in the descriptions by checking if the name of the brand from column A is existing if yes should be capitalized if not move to the next row and so one

any solution for that, I got stack on that here is a sample from the data set

> column A
>
> & Other Stories

> #HomeOffice
>
> 1-800-FLOWERS.COM, INC.
>
> 10 Corso Como
>
> 100% CAPRI
>
> ITALIA SRL
>
> Column B
>
> They believe in sharing stories. their concept is built around
> inviting ctomers to be involved in the creative process behind the
> brand. They share everything from the sketch of a shoe to the behind
> the scenes of a photo shoot, and views from their ateliers in paris,
> stockholm and los angeles. Words such as personal, diverse and
> uncomplicated are present in everything they do. They aim to create
> collections for all fashion loving women. They want to encourage
> personal style with their wide range of products and make everyone
> feel welcome. By keeping things uncomplicated and flexible, it’s easy
> for them to adapt to new visions and different collections as fashion
> always changes. That’s the beauty of it! their Collections are
> designed in their three ateliers: paris, stockholm and los angeles.
> They are each fantastic yet very different cities. They love the
> contrast between the passionate parisian atmosphere, the minimalist,
> pragmatic stockholm feel, and the laidback los angeles vibe, and
> especially what happens when they all come together. Each person
> working with & other stories is an essential part of their group of
> creatives and valued individual within the company. They believe in
> being spontaneo, personal and flexible, which makes it easy to
> collaborate within all parts of their brand and enables growth, for
> you and . Currently, & other stories has over 1, 500 employees and
> continues to expand, opening more stores around the world.
>
> #Homeoffice Creates a unique, original workplace with a long service life. Stainable sitting sta desks, ergonomic seats and high quality
> accessories make your home workplace unique and ergonomic. Pure dutch
> design. Go to http: //www. Hashtaghomeoffice. Nl for more information
> and inspiration!
> #Homeoffice Creates a unique, original workplace with a long service life. Stainable sitting sta desks, ergonomic seats and high quality
> accessories make your home workplace unique and ergonomic. Pure dutch
> design. Go to http: //www.hashtaghomeoffice. Nl for more information
> and inspiration!
>
> Founded in 1991, 10 corso como is recognized as the first concept
> destination, blending culture with trends, promoting a close link
> between fashion and design. Known as the first «concept store», it
> turned the retail concept in a hub for lifestyle and fashion. Today,
> 30 years later, 10 corso como, with the new presidency and
> entrepreneurship of tiziana fati, together with the artistic direction
> of carla sozzani, continues the same integrity and aesthetic identity
> that has made 10 corso como a symbol of milan, of creativity and made
> in italy. For further information about 10 corso como visit www.
> 10corsocomo. Com connect with 10 corso como on instagram: @10corsocomo
>
> The 100% capri luxury brand was born in 2000 from the idea of ​​toni
> aiello who, focing everything on quality, on rich history and on the
> charm of made in italy, it is aimed at a target of ctomers who love
> lifestyle and the good life, who spend the summer in capri and winter
> in saint moritz, also making incursion to the caribbean. People who
> like to spend, but who ask first of all. The foc straight to the
> linen, why did you want an inseparable combination with 100% capri, a
> little? How To do the red luxury car and the ferrari brand. Today
> thanks to new technologies the tailoring is able to offer fifteen
> different qualities of material, from waterproof linen at lino's garza
> and offer collections for men, women, children, but also for the home.
> Aiello "wears" even boats and planes. All by invoiced by tens of
> millions of euros and an international presence all over the world.
> From capri to the fascinating hotel de rsie in rome, from st.
> Barthelemy (elegant and refined island of the french antilles) to bal
> harbour in florida (the most luxurio mall in the united states), from
> sicily (inside the prestigio vegetable golf) to cape town. Openings
> are also scheduled for abu dhabi and hong kong.

Thanks

Comment: What is the brand name in column A in given example?

Comment: listed like that : column A

[(& Other Stories

#HomeOffice

1-800-FLOWERS.COM, INC.

10 Corso Como

100% CAPRI

ITALIA SRL]

Comment: so brand name is `FLOWERS.COM, INC.` ? if so where it is in column B?

Comment: if its not there we should not do anything and move to the next row

Comment: I"m still confused @midomid ....You told you want to captilize brand names in column B that are in column A.....Entire columnA is one brand name? or part of the columnA is brand name?....In any case I don't see matching brandnames in column B....It's very big text...Can you simplify your example?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/249481/discussion-between-midomid-and-bhargav).

Comment: for example take this brand name "#HomeOffice" from column A and check if its excist here the in the column B "#Homeoffice Creates a unique, original workplace with a long service life. Stainable sitting sta desks..." if yes should turn it to capital letter "#HOMEOFFICE"

Comment: Sorry for late busy with work

Comment: @Bhargav it's okay I'm waiting until I receive an answer